# Implicit function theorem and constrained maximization

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, implicit-function-theorem

For simplicity, consider the following constrained maximization problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{maximize}}
& & F(x,y) \\
& \text{subject to}
& &  x + y = 1,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
with $F(x,y)$ concave.
We then have the following system of equations from the first order condition:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& F_1(x,y) - F_2(x,y) = 0\\
& x + y = 1,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $F_i(x,y)$ is the derivative wrt the $i$ argument.
Now suppose I want to find $\frac{dx}{dy}$ around the solution $(x^*,y^*)$. Using the implicit function theorem however, we get two different expressions depending on wich equation we use:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{F_{22}-F_{12}}{F_{11} - F_{21}}\\
& \frac{dx}{dy} = -1,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

### Now my question are:

1. Does it make sense to evaluate the first expression in $(x^*,y^*)$ (thus applying the implicit function theorem and disregarding the second).
2. Why we cannot use the second expression, since we cannot evaluate it at $(x^*,y^*)$?
3. Are there some conditions not satisifed in this setting that prevent us from using the implcit function theorem?

Comment: Yes, the constraint matters at the optimum. So $x + y  = 1$ at the optimum.

Comment: Let $\lambda$ be the Lagrange multiplier associated to the constraint. Then from the FOC we have $F_1 = \lambda$ and also $F_2 = \lambda$. So $F_1 = F_2$ or $F_1 - F_2 = 0$